# Unwanted time conversation in JSON date filed involved in Kendo Grid Ajax data bind

Tags: kendo-grid

We are using Ajax data bind to display data in Kendo grid. 
MVC controller is sending JSON result to grid which contains a date filed.
MVC JSON serializer  converts Date value  as /Date(***Epoc Time****)/

When Kenod grid display data , it converts above date value into local time zone.   Our requirement is , what  ever the date value we are sending form server should appears into grid as it is.

Let us know , if you have any workaround for  this.